# Can I use jQuery to check if a list item is present or not?

Tags: jquery

I have the following select list:

```
<select id="AccountID">
  <option value='0000'>Select Account</option>
  <option value='002M'>test1</option>
  <option value='002N'>test2</option>
  <option value='002P'>test3</option>
</select>
```

After a user makes a new selection I need to execute the following which will replace the above list with one that does not contain the choice "Select Account"

```
function SelectAccounts() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "/Administration/Accounts/GetOptions",
        data: { ds: $('#DataSourceID').val(),
            ac: '0000'
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#AccountID').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Is there a way that I can change:

```
$('#AccountID').change(SelectAccounts);
```

so that it only calls SelectAccounts IF there is an option "0000" in the select list?

Comment: Why do you alter the list in response to the user selecting an item in that same list? Isn't that a bit confusing for them given that their selection will immediately disappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, just use an anonymous function:

```
$('#AccountID').change(function() {
  if ($(this).find('option[value="0000"]').length > 0) {
    SelectAccounts();
  } else {
    // Option not present
  }
);
```

Or a selector:

```
$(document).on('change', '#AccountID:has(option[value="0000"])', SelectAccounts);
// Use a more specific selector for the parent of `#AccountID`.
```

Comment: That selector will either set the change handler or not depending on whether the option exists at that time, it won't prevent the handler from running in the future if the option is removed.

Comment: I think `.on()` acts as `.live()` as well.

Answer (score 2):

In a general sense you can test if the select element has a particular option as follows:

```
if ($("#AccountID option[value='0000']").length > 0) {
    // option exists
}
```

However, you might be better off just removing the change handler:

```
// within the success handler of your ajax call:

$("#AccountID").html(data).off("change");
```

Or, if using an older version of jQuery, use `.unbind("change")`.

Comment: I am not quite sure about the `.off()` method. Were you basing on the assumption that the OP only wanted to change the option list *once*?

Comment: @Siku-Siku.Com - Well she didn't provide much information, but the code as currently shown does one and only one thing on change, and that is call the `SelectAccounts()` function. She said she didn't want to do that after the options list was reloaded, so removing the handler doesn't seem unreasonable. (Why on earth you'd replace the options list as soon as an option is chosen _in the same list_ is beyond me, but anyway.) I _did_ first indicate how to do the conditional test, so...

Comment: That makes sense (+1). I thought I had a wrong understanding of `.off()`; that's why I asked. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

sure, you just ask:

```
if(!!$("#AccountID option[value=0000]").length)) {
    // code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
$('#AccountID').change(function() {
  if ($(this).find('option[value="0000"]').length > 0) {
    SelectAccounts();
  }
});
```

Just curious, do you really need to alter the options using AJAX? If they are pretty simple, maybe prepare them in advance?